# Do I have to use a Mac to develop JavaFX for iOS

Tags: java, ios, javafx, gluon-mobile

The documentation http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.1/#_ios says that I need "A Mac with MacOS X 10.9 or superior" to develop for iOS. But I don't understand: if I have Windows and everything on it already (Gradle, my IDE, all the plugins and SDKs also for Android) and I develop simultaneously for iOS and Android using the Gluon plugin I can't *really* develop for iOS? If I want to develop for both I have to install everything on a Mac?

Comment: Always these downvotes for no reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop but you cannot build iOS image, run it in iOS simulator or deploy to the device. These tasks can only be done on Mac

Comment: Can I create some sort of task on Windows that can be executed on Mac which will build the the app?

Comment: I can only see it if you have a build server on Mac, which pulls your code in from the code repository and builds it.